# Nesting an array in Jekyll with YAML

Tags: arrays, jekyll, liquid

If I have this block in YAML:

```
- project:
  -
    name: Whiskers
    top_category: Cats
    thumb_url: thumb.jpg
    main:
      - image: cat.jpg
```

Is it possible to chain one of the lines, as in:

```
- project:
  -
    name: Whiskers
    top_category: Cats
    thumb_url: thumb.jpg
    main:
      - image_data: cat.jpg, Somealttext!
```

And then access it as:

`<img src="cat.jpg" alt="Somealttext!" />`

?

If so, what would the Liquid layout look like?

```
{% for main in project.main %}
    {{ ??? }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider having a data file `_data/project.yml`:

```
- project:
  -
    name: Whiskers
    top_category: Cats
    thumb_url: thumb.jpg
    main:
      - image_data: cat.jpg, Somealttext!
```

Then we access `main`:

```
{% assign main = site.data.project[0].project[0].main[0] %}
```

And split the content of `image_data` assuming the `image_alt` won't contain any commas:

```
{% assign data = main.image_data|split:"," %}
```

Then we can access its values as:

```
{{ data[0] }}
<br>
{{ data[1] }}

<img src="{{data[0]}}" alt="{{data[1]}}" />
```

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!